# Expect script to run Ansible playbooks

Tags: ssh, ansible, expect, sudo

I have written an Ansible playbook which prompts me to enter password interactively for SSH and SUDO like below.

```
$ ansible-playbook -i test --limit dev  app_name.yml  -vv --tags=stop
SSH password:
SUDO password[defaults to SSH password]:
```

There are various options available with Ansible like defining password in ansible_ssh_password under group_vars but it don't seem to work for me since I can't have sshpass installed in my target server nor I am allowed to make any changes to my sudoers file.

I tried to execute ansible-playbook from a little expect script below

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set password PASSWORD
set where_to_execute  [lindex $argv 0]
set which_app_to_execute  [lindex $argv 1]
set what_to_execute  [lindex $argv 2]

send "ansible-playbook -i test --limit $where_to_execute $which_app_to_execute  -vv --tags=$what_to_execute \r"
expect "SSH password:"
send "$password \r"
expect "SUDO password*"
send "$password \r"
expect "$"
send "exit \r"
```

Unfortunately this is also not working may be because SSH process is not spawned by expect. Did anyone try this method and got things working. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide your playbook code?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. This is just not happening with playbook, even if i wanna execute some adhoc commands through Ansible it prompts me for password which is expected and which is what I wanna automate inputting password through expect

Comment: Please tell me if you're not familiar with python. I can give you a little extra help to translate your expect script to pexpect

Comment: That expect script isn't spawning any commands to talk to. Did you try spawning that `ansible` command? Instead of `send`ing it to nowhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your expect scripts is that you aren't actually running the ansible command there (or any command for that matter).

You use

```
send "ansible-playbook -i test --limit $where_to_execute $which_app_to_execute  -vv --tags=$what_to_execute \r"
```

which *sends* that string to ... nowhere as far as I know. There's nowhere for it to go.

What you **want** to be doing is `spawn`ing that ansible command and then using expect to communicate with it.

Something like this:

```
spawn ansible-playbook -i test --limit $where_to_execute $which_app_to_execute  -vv --tags=$what_to_execute
```

You may also want to set the `timeout` value if the ansible command can take a little while (to prevent `expect` from killing it when it doesn't return quickly enough).

Answer (score 1):

It works for me using the python implementation of expect. [pexpect](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/)

install pexpect using pip: `pip install pexpect`

You can use this code as an workaround for your expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pexpect

def main(args):

  #Setup variables
  password, where, which, what = args

  cmd = "ansible-playbook -i test --limit %s %s  -vv --tags=%s" % (where, which, what)

  child = pexpect.spawn(cmd)
  child.sendline(password)
  child.expect('SSH password:')
  child.sendline(password)
  child.expect('SUDO password*')
  child.expect(pexpect.EOF)

  print child.before


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv[1:])
```

This is the most simple example but it's working fine for me.

`./myscript.py mypassword dev app_name.yml stop`

As @Etan Reisner pointed out, the main difference between your code that isn't working and my pexpect code is the `spawn` ansible command. The above code on expect also works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn /usr/bin/ansible -m ping myserver --ask-pass
expect "SSH password:"
send "mypassword\r"
expect "$ "
```

Comment: You spawn the ansible command the OP doesn't. That's probably the difference.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Just tried on expect script using `spawn` instead of `send`